# JEditorPane scrolling to the current caret position

Tags: java, scroll, jeditorpane

I have a JEditorPane which I use to display an HTML document.    the document has hyperlinks embedded in it.   When a user clicks on a bookmark a position the caret to the associated place in the JeditorPane.   The JeditorPane is then suppose to scroll to this position.   This works mostly.  But, I noticed that if the document has a lot of "break tags" (BR) tags embedded in it, the scrolling does not position the JEditorPane to right place.   It's like the  tags throw the callebration off.    Any suggestions on what to do about this?

Comment: Why not post your http://sscce.org/ and a link to the troublesome HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the underlying problem and want to restate the question rather than cause confusion based on the original question.   I wish stackoverflow allowed questions to be withdrawn!